# How to downsample a matrix in columns ? MATLAB

Tags: image-processing, matlab

I am studying wavelets in image processing. I would like to learn how to downsample a matrix in columns using MATLAB. I have used the `downsample(x,n)` command to downsample the given matrix in rows. But how to do the same in columns?

x =

```
 1     2     3
 4     5     6
 7     8     9
10    11    12
```

y = downsample(x,2)

y =

```
 1     2     3
 7     8     9
```

But I would like to get the following result.

```
y=
     1       3
     4       6
     7       9
    10      12
```

How to do it in MATLAB? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe Off-Topic here, but anyway !

Try it

```
y = downsample(x',2)'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .. It works.. It's simple. Don't know how I missed it. Thanks again.

Answer (score -3):

Do not use the downsample function.

I used simple method in MATLAB:

```
x= [1 2 3;
    4 5 6;
    7 8 9;
    10 11 12];

x1=x(:,1:2:end)
```

Have a good time. ^^